# Looking to correct my After Update Event (MS Access)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm currently using the below code to update certain fields so that the user doesn't have to enter them. For some reason, it only fires on records that are already saved and ignores the current record.

The funny thing is that it was working for a day or so (including the current record). Then Access started crashing on me and I was forced to re-write the code.

```
Private Sub RawMaterial_AfterUpdate()
sSQL = "UPDATE tmp_Formula INNER JOIN tbl_RawMaterial ON tmp_Formula.RawMaterial = tbl_RawMaterial.RawMaterial " _
     & "SET tmp_Formula.MiscInfo = [tbl_RawMaterial].[MiscInfo], tmp_Formula.Potency = [tbl_RawMaterial].[Potency], " _
     & "tmp_Formula.PUoM = [tbl_RawMaterial].[PUoM], tmp_Formula.CUoM = [tbl_RawMaterial].[ClaimUoM], " _
     & "tmp_Formula.Cost = [tbl_RawMaterial].[Cost], tmp_Formula.CostUoM = [Tbl_RawMaterial].[CostUoM];"
CurrentDb.Execute sSQL, dbFailOnError
CurrentDb.TableDefs.Refresh
Me.Refresh
End Sub
```

Would anyone be able to help me re-write this so that it includes the current record? It is probably irrelevant but I have tried Me.CurrentRecord.SetFocus and Me.RawMaterial.SetFocus. Neither worked.

Comment: Probably main issue is the record is not yet committed to table when the SQL is run. Also, the SQL is updating every record in tmp_Formula. Might want to limit the update to just one record with a WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks for the useful comment. By adding WHERE (((tmp_Formula.RawMaterial)='" & RawMaterial & "')) to my code, the update only fires on one record at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New record (or edits to existing record) must first be committed to table to be available for any SQL. A record is committed when:
1. close table/query/form
or
2. move to another record
or
3. run code to save - options:

a. `If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False`

b. `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord`

Comment: Almost forgot to thank you. By adding 3.a. to my code, it ran successfully. Thank you!